# what are the different technologies available for communication among software components distributed across networked computers?

Tags: com+, corba, dcom

I want to know what are the different technologies available for communication among software components distributed across networked computers? 
And which is the recent and popular one.

Comment: It would be easier to provide some options if you could explain the application purpose (what kind of data needs to be communicated, and what kind of technology connects those networked computers)

Comment: this questions isn't useful and the user did not take care about.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of your software (embedded or enterprise) and on the domain you're working on.

I would consider the following technologies:

- SOAP
- CORBA
- Protobuf (or Thrift) over socket